vba validaton font color issue
Thanks for the support,please help I have attached the code that I tried doing the below
I have a issue where I have to retain the font color of each words in cell that has delimiter comma.
first i do validation of checking the cell value if the first letter is capital and the Initials are all capital then join them back to display in cell but currently the font color are changing to last word color
eg: Arun a, kmaal k,Jack js
if Arun a is yellow
kmaal k is red
Jack js is saffron
then it should display Arun A, Kmaal K, Jack JS in the same color each word mentioned above however below code is showing all in same color
                    Dim cellvalued As String
Dim wordarrayed As Variant
Dim newtext
Dim wordarrayed2 As Variant
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Val
Dim p As Long
Dim orgnal As Long
Dim modcelled As String
cellvalued = Range("h" & t).Value
Set Cell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Congress Materials").Range("h" & t)
Val = Cell.Value

wordarrayed = Split(cellvalued, ",")

For p = LBound(wordarrayed) To UBound(wordarrayed)
'orgnal = wordarrayed(p).Font.ColorIndex
orgnal = Cell.Characters(Start:=InStr(Cell.Value, wordarrayed(p)), Length:=Len(wordarrayed(p))).Font.Color
wordarrayed(p) = StrConv(wordarrayed(p), vbProperCase)

wordarrayed2 = Split(wordarrayed(p), " ")
If UBound(wordarrayed2) > 0 Then
wordarr = StrConv(wordarrayed2(o + 1), vbUpperCase)
wordarrayed(p) = wordarrayed2(o) & " " & wordarr
'wordarrayed(p).Characters
End If
'newtext = wordarrayed(p)
Cell.Characters(Start:=InStr(Cell.Value, wordarrayed(p)), Length:=Len(wordarrayed(p))).Font.Color = orgnal
Next p
modcelled = Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, wordarrayed)

'modcelled = orgnal

Range("h" & t).Value = modcelled


You're going to run into all kinds of issues with the logic you're using.  Names like Smith-Jones, DeLeon, names without initials or some of the sillier names people are coming up with (I know a couple who named their daughter JayMe) are going to break things pretty badly for you.

Range("h" & t).Value = modcelled overwrites the cell value and destroys any per-character font properties.   Aslo this wordarrayed2(o + 1) - what is o here?

Option Explicit

Sub validate()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, t As Long, rng As Range
    Dim colColor As Collection, colPosn As Collection
    
    Set colPosn = New Collection
    Set colColor = New Collection
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Congress Materials")
    
    t = 1
    Set rng = ws.Cells(t, "H")
    
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    Dim c As Long, lastc As Long
    
    ' initial color
    lastc = rng.Characters(1, 1).Font.Color
    n = 1
    colColor.Add lastc, CStr(n)
    colPosn.Add 1, CStr(n)
    
    ' scan along each character of string for color change
    For i = 2 To Len(rng)
         c = rng.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color
         If c <> lastc Then
             ' add to collection
             n = n + 1
             colColor.Add c, CStr(n)
             colPosn.Add i, CStr(n)
             lastc = c
             'Debug.Print n, i, c
         End If
    Next
    ' last postion
    colPosn.Add i, CStr(n + 1)
    
    ' process string
    Dim ar, ar2, v, v2, s As String
    ar = Split(rng, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
        ' leading spaces
        s = ar(i)
        n = Len(s) - Len(LTrim(s))
        
        ' split name into parts by space
        ar2 = Split(LTrim(s), " ")
        ar2(0) = StrConv(ar2(0), vbProperCase)
        
        ' initials
        If UBound(ar2) > 0 Then
            ar2(1) = UCase(ar2(1))
        End If
        
        ' join parts back together
        ar(i) = Space(n) & Join(ar2, " ")
    Next
    rng = Join(ar, ",")
     
    ' restore coloring
    n = colColor.Count
    For i = 1 To n
        x = colPosn(i)
        y = colPosn(i + 1)
        rng.Characters(x, y - x).Font.Color = colColor(i)
   Next

   MsgBox n & " colors", vbInformation

End Sub

